# Is it possible for me to get into a PhD program with low GPA

Tags: phd, gre, gpa

PhD programs I’ve applied to: UTD, NYU, UMD, MIT, U of Florida, Stanford, PSU, UPenn, U of Chicago, MSU, USC, CMU, Purdue, Columbia, HKU,

Background:

Education: Bachelor: Hengyang Normal University( 2 years) with 3.09 GPA+

Hunan Vocational College for Nationalties ( 3 years) with 3.47 GPA

Master program: University of Maryland, College Park ( 3.03 GPA Supply Chain MGMT) ( In the winter of first semester, I was diagnosed with TMJ pain, I told my professor that fact where I had headache but he ignored my email and replied me until final exam came, then we argued with that and he gave me a D, then my GPA suddenly falls above 3.0, after that I have been trying to bring it up back to 3.0, by taking some independent study; However, after the news spread across other professor, they all graded me with a B-. Finally, I graduated with a 3.03 GPA. The director has indirectly refused to accept me as PHD student because of my GPA and limitation of funds.

GRE: V:165 Q:167 AW: 3 ; TOEFL: waivor

Credentials: Certified Supply Chain Professional(CSCP), Certified Transportation and Logistics; IBM Data Science Professional; Advanced Data Science with IBM( AI, ML..); Blockchain IoT for Supply Chain; Blockchain foundation developer.

Question: Do I still have chance to get offer from the universities that I have applied to? and what’s you suggestion for me ( the deadline for PHD Program still remains 1–2 months)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

Comment: Can you explain what GPA, GPA+ and the numbers mean?

Answer (score 2):

I notice you are aiming pretty high given your GPA. A more fruitful strategy would be to pick a small number of topics you are really interested in, and try to find departments/professors in less prestigious universities that do interesting research in those topics. Not all great research happens at the top universities. Applying to those would be easier because you already thought about why you and that department are a good match.